# Can we launch a parallel shell command from python?

Tags: python, shell, parallel-processing

I want to use a `go` executable: [timescaledb-parallel-copy](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-parallel-copy) to insert data into database from a csv file. However, I plan to use Python for reading in the filename and lookup the appropriate table name for insertion. If I then launch `timescaledb-parallel-copy` as a Python subprocess to execute on shell, will it still be parallel? I do not need Python to make it parallel, it is parallel by default. I just do not want Python to make it single-threaded.

Comment: How could Python make it single-threaded? The GIL is an internal attribute of the Python interpreter. Subprocesses are across a process boundary; they're completely unaffected.

Comment: (I also wouldn't call a go executable a "shell command" at all; if you're doing it right, with `shell=False`, there's no shell involved anywhere, just the Python interpreter `fork()`ing itself and `execve()`ing the Go program -- and even if you're doing it wrong and using `shell=True`, the shell that the Python interpreter `fork()`s and `exec()`s is just `fork()`ing off a copy of *itself* and using `execve()` to replace that copy with the Go executable's process image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `subprocess.run()` then your program, `timescaledb-parallel-copy` will execute as if you had called it from the shell.  It will still be in parallel.  The python script will not be, and will wait on `timescaledb-parallel-copy` to return.

Comment: I was able to test that the subprocess runs in parallel if it wants to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe it will be. By launching the program as a subprocess,  you are running the program as it originally would be, with no interference from python.